# Progressive matrix question - squares, circles, triangles in the corners

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

This question comes from www.test-iq.org's free demo IQ test. I took the extremely short test just for fun. I had no problem in doing the other questions, but I have problem in doing this question:
[image]

I did find out a pattern in the shapes in the squares, but I did not find out a pattern that governs where the shapes are in the square. Any help in this problem would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is

> F

Because:

> If you look at each individual shape from left to right, top to bottom,
>  the shapes position moves clockwise.
>  This explains the position in the top-left.

Comment: I think this is the better answer. Other answers are saying "two out of three shapes in each row have the same position" but it's also true that two out of three shapes in each *column* have the same position, which is an equally good pattern that's broken by F.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is:

> F

because...

> Horizontally, in each row, there are 3 shapes in total in the square - circle, square and triangle. In the third row, the square is missing, leaving us with options D and F. Also, from the first two rows, there are 2 squares where the shapes inside them share the same position. Since none of the positions of shapes in the first two pictures of the third row is the same, the only solution found in options A-F that is correct is option F, since the square is on the top left, which is that of the second picture of the third row.

Comment: Wonderful first answer! This is a very good explanation. Welcome to PSE.

Answer (score 3):

> Basically there are 3 shapes, for each row. Row 3 leaves only Squares, then each row has two shapes that share the same corner and so the answer is F.

Comment: Can you add the observation from my answer to your answer for completeness?

Answer (score 0):

> For me a bit more ambiguous and therefore D.
>  We start with bottom right, bottom right, top right, bottom left, bottom right.
>  And now everything is mirrored. Bottom left, bottom left, top left - so we continue with top left.